# Limiting to one result on inner join table

Tags: mysql, join, limit

Hi I have the following query:

```
SELECT pr.*, img.image_file, c.contract_id, c.cmin_markup, c.cmeal_plan, c.tax_include, c.civa, m.plan_name, r.room_name, r.room_id FROM contracts AS c
INNER JOIN meal_plan AS m ON m.plan_code = c.cmeal_plan AND m.lang = '1'
INNER JOIN room_infos AS r ON r.hotel_id = '$hid' AND r.lang = '1'

LEFT JOIN images AS img ON img.foreign_id = r.room_id LIMIT 1

LEFT JOIN promotions as pr ON pr.hotel_id = '$hid' AND FIND_IN_SET('c.contract_id', pr.contract_id) > 0 AND FIND_IN_SET('r.room_id', pr.room_id) > 0 AND pr.travel_start <= '$now' AND pr.travel_end >= '$now' AND pr.book_start <= '$arriving' AND pr.book_end >= '$departing' AND pr.lang='1'
WHERE c.hotel_id = '$hid' AND c.cstart <= '$arriving' AND c.cend >= '$departing' AND c.ctype = '1'"
```

I need to limit the images table to give me only one result. I am not sure if this is possibe or how would be the best way to achieve this. If more information is needed please let me know. It is a lot of tables to post. Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: what relation does the images table has with room? Does a room has more than one Image? ...

Comment: yes a room can have more than one image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include a group by to the end of your query. Assuming your images table has an ID field simply append "GROUP BY images.id"

Comment: I simply added the foreign_id and it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have mySql instance in front of me to try this but consider moving images into a subquery:

```
LEFT JOIN (select * from images LIMIT 1) AS img on img.foreign_id = r.room_id
```

This of course is not very efficient on its own as there is no where clause in the inline subquery, you can improve the subquery to be more restricting and have it join with the parent query.

Something like this:

```
select * from images as img2 where img2.foreign_id = r.room_id LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks for answering... this does not return any images.